# How can I get the reputation of filehashes on Virustotal using request and bs4 module and not using Virustotal's PublicAPI?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My requirement is to check multiple filehashes's reputation on Virustotal using python. I do not want to use Virustotal's Public API since there is a cap of 4 requests/min. I thought of using requests module and beautiful soup to get this done.

Please check the link below:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f8ee4c00a3a53206d8d37abe5ed9f4bfc210a188cd5b819d3e1f77b34504061e/summary

I need to capture 54/69 for this file. I have a list of filehashes in an excel which I can loop for detection status once I can get it done for this one hash.

But I am not able to get the specific count of engines detected the filehash as malicious. The CSS selector for the count is giving me only a blank list. Please help. Please check the code I have written below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

filehash='F8EE4C00A3A53206D8D37ABE5ED9F4BFC210A188CD5B819D3E1F77B34504061E'
filehash_lower = filehash.lower()
URL = 'https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/' +filehash+'/detection'

response = requests.get(URL)
print(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
detection_details = soup.select('div.detections')
print(detection_details)
```

Comment: Seems like the source of the page contains an empty HTML page, that is to be filled by a JavaScript helper that probably gathers the data from the API itself. Why don't you want to use their API? If you have a "good" reason, the only solution may be to use a browser driver (eg Selenium) and make it wait for the page to be loaded, and then gather the data your need. For a high number of hashes, that will probably take a long time, though.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your input. Actually their public API can accomodate only 4 requests/ min and since I have high number of hashes I thought of using beautiful soap to extract specific data from the HTML page. I am new to python and also don't have any coding background. Not much knowledge of HTML as well.

Comment: The page is dynamic. Sometimes you can find the data within the `<script>` tags. Unfortunately that is NOT the case here. The other option then is as suggested before, is to use Selenium so the page renders before pulling the html source

Comment: Someone just now answered my question and provided the code below which works fine but now I am not able to find out the answer. What did just happen? Also, if someone can help me to understand this line of code, it will be really helpful (s = r['data'][0]['attributes']['text'])

import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.virustotal.com/ui/files/f8ee4c00a3a53206d8d37abe5ed9f4bfc210a188cd5b819d3e1f77b34504061e/comments?relationships=item,author').json()
s = r['data'][0]['attributes']['text']
ratio = re.search(r'Detection Ratio:(.*)',s).groups(0)[0].strip()
print(ratio)

Comment: If a website has a public API that has a rate limit, then an attempt to exceed that rate limit by bypassing that API is by definition an abuse of service. This is a good way to launch an unintentional denial-of-service attack on a service, and also a good way to get yourself blocked, by increasingly aggressive mechanisms if you continue.

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal if you abuse their "private API" by exploiting the way their webpages send requests to them, they might just block you after identifying you as an abuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using the ajax calls :

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'x-app-hostname': 'https://www.virustotal.com/gui/',
    'dnt': '1',
    'x-app-version': '20190611t171116',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,la;q=0.6,mt;q=0.5',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'authority': 'www.virustotal.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.virustotal.com/',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.virustotal.com/ui/files/f8ee4c00a3a53206d8d37abe5ed9f4bfc210a188cd5b819d3e1f77b34504061e', headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.content)
malicious = data['data']['attributes']['last_analysis_stats']['malicious']
undetected = data['data']['attributes']['last_analysis_stats']['undetected']

print(malicious, 'malicious out of', malicious + undetected)
```

output:

> 54 malicious out of 69

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastien for your help. This works well incase the filehash is malicious but if it is clean and not detected by any scanners then it is throwing an error. I will right an if else statement for this and hope will get it done. Thanks.

Comment: have an example hash?

Comment: FD56FA9D1FECA307A50C04A48C15C140BD4762038C89D86888850E13670AA189. It is a hash of one of the exe I have created from python script. Since no one has previously uploaded the exe, VT doesn't have any reputation for the same.

Comment: Are you sure this hash works anyway? If I try https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/fd56fa9d1feca307a50c04a48c15c140bd4762038c89d86888850e13670aa189/summary , the page is not found

Comment: I have a doubt, how did you get this URL https://www.virustotal.com/ui/files/F8EE4C00A3A53206D8D37ABE5ED9F4BFC210A188CD5B819D3E1F77B34504061E/...? Normally if I go to the site and enter the filehash it will give me the URL given below:https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f8ee4c00a3a53206d8d37abe5ed9f4bfc210a188cd5b819d3e1f77b34504061e/detection

Comment: In your Chrome console you can monitor network traffic. I got it there

Comment: I am not able to find it. Can you please show me where exactly it is?

Comment: Thanks @SebastienD. My code is working fine now. Thanks a lot for your help.